# Is there an easy way to create and use a huge amount of counters in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to analyse some data and I want to classify it according to the attributes found in objects of a class. I have three attributes in total. One attribute that can be in a range like 1..2, ... , 6..7, one attribute that can be in a range like 0..5, ... , 15..20, and the last one is a Boolean that can be true or false.

A obvious solution to the problem would be to create all the counters needed (and I believe I probably will have to) but that is 6 * 5 * 2 = 60 variables. And the code to treat these variables, even using Kotlin's when will certainly be a monstruosity.

I would like to classify these objects in a way that my code is cleanest possible. Thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a data class with 3 properties (two integers and a boolean), let's call it Category, and a Map<Category, Counter>.

Comment: What should I specify? I don't believe that it's a burden in terms of memory, but the code that triggers those counters will be extreamily long and dense, I'm trying to avoid this.

Comment: @JBNizet Exactly. I'm not familiarized with maps, but by the things i'm reading it would help a lot by not having so many variables declaration.

Comment: Then... read about them. Map/HashMap have javadoc. They're a very well-known and documented data structure, and explaining what a HashMap is is too broad for StackOverflow. Do experiments.

Comment: You might find it easier to use `List.groupBy()` to create the map.